# Abelianization derivator

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

About ten-fifteen years ago, when the theory of abstract triangulated categories reached a culminating point (after the publication of Neeman's book http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Neeman/triangulatedcats.pdf),
it was clear that in this area the interplay between triangulated and abelian categories played a central role. Sure the transfer of properties between the two cases is done via so called homological functors. Derivators are certainly created in
order to deal with triangulated categories, overcoming some unpleasant features of them (e. g. the lack of functoriality). I'm wandering how to capture the interplay with abelian categories at this level. As the first step, if a strong, stable derivator $D$ is given, we can  construct the prederivator $A$, where $A(I)$ is the abelianization of the triangulated category $D(I)$, for every small category $I$. Thus every homological functor from $D(I)$ to an arbitrary abelian category has to factor through an exact functor defined on $A(I)$. It seems to be not hard to show that $A$ is actually a derivator. Since $A(I)$ is complete, perhaps homotopy (co)limits coincide to usual (co)limits (but I'm not sure). Now the subsequent questions are: Is the derivator $A$ strong (it can't be stable, since the category $A(I)$ is not triangulated)?  What other properties has $A$ to satisfy? I guess, it should be a corespondent for stability, giving the abelian structure of $A(I)$ and, more important, 
the exactness of induced functors $u^*,u_*$ and $u_!$ for every functor between small categories $u:I\to J$.
I tried unsuccessfully to find any paper where similar questions are addressed. Can someone indicate me a reference?

Comment: Well... if you want homotopy co/limits to be categorical co/limits the natural assumption to make is that the derivator $A$ is "discrete", in the sense that all the diagram functors $A(I)\rightarrow A(1)^I$ are actually equivalences. In that case, the categories $A(I)$ are all Abelian if and only if the base $A(1)$ is Abelian.

Comment: An example of such an Abelian derivators naturally occurs as follows: if you take a strong and stable derivator $D$, and a $t$-structure on $D(1)$, then you can define the "heart-derivator" $H$ where $H(I)$ is the category of those coherent diagrams with components are in the heart. It turns out that this is a derivator and that it is discrete and Abelian in the above sense.

This is based on the following two preprints: 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.07540 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01505 (see Corollary 3.4 in this second preprint)

Comment: Thanks Simone! Actually it was only a guess, but it seems to me the diagram functors are not equivalences.